# Sencha Touch: getValues() returns empty object

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I'm new to Sencha Touch and I need to know what I am doing wrong.
My app needs to create customers.

NewCustomer.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.NewCustomer', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    ...
    config: {
        id: 'newCustomerForm',
        ...
    }
}
```

Customers.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Customers', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    ...
    config: {
        refs: {
            saveCustomerBtn: {
                selector: 'button#saveCustomerBtn',
                xtype: 'Ext.Button'
            },
            newCustomerForm: {
                selector: '#newCustomerForm',
                xtype: 'Ext.form.Panel'
            }
       },

       control: {
           "saveCustomerBtn": {
               tap: 'onSaveCustomerBtnTap'
           }
       }
    },

    onSaveCustomerBtnTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var newCustomerForm = this.getNewCustomerForm();
        console.log(newCustomerForm.getValues());
    }
}
```

I want to grab the form values but when I tap the save customer button in my console appears:

```
Object {}
```

Comment: Have you added this view name in your Application.js ?

Comment: The *control* object needs to be inside *config*

Comment: You are right @arthurakay, my code has control inside config. I copied it wrong. I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I forgot to fill in the name attribute of the form fields. I should have added a name property bound to each field as, according to the doc:

**getValues()**: Returns an object containing the value of each field in the form, keyed to the field's name.

Thanks for the help